# Migration are run regardless of the branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, ruby-on-rails-4.2, schema.rb

I am working on different branches, and on these branches there are migration files. There is a `schema.rb` file.

My issue is that no matter what branch I am currently on, running migration changes the `schema.rb` in a way, as if it took into account all migrations on all branches.

Say, I have created `Foo` model on branch `A` with corresponding table `foos`, run a migration and switched to another branch.

Running some other migration (say creating table `bars`) on my current branch `B`, where there is no `foos` table, creates it:

```
# while on branch B
Foo
#=> NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('foos')
#=> true
```

Question: **How do I make `schema.rb` to change only according to migrations on current branch?**

Answer (score 5):

`db:migrate` or `db:rollback` job writes `schema.rb` file from user database schema, not from user migration script. even though you change git branch, your database state is not changed. So `foos` table exists but `Foo` model does not exist.

My Answer: Just rollback before checkout branch, or Writing git hook script for rollback everytime you checkout branch

Comment: I think rollback is a valid option here, but I'd like to establish something more robust, so that I do not have to rollback each time I switch branch. Can you think of anything?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko how about writing git hook script that compare migration version between master and current branch and rollback. it execute when checkout new branch

Answer (score 2):

Use per branch databases and connection settings.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your `schema.rb` ignored on git. One solution would be not to ignore this file. Take a look at `.gitignore` on the root folder of your project and take schema.rb out of there.

If it's not in `.gitignore` your problem has nothing to do with `schema.rb` as it should be different for each branch. The problem is probably that you only have one local database file and you are running migrations from different branches on the same database, that's why you get:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('foos')
#=> true
```

You should have a different copy of the database for each branch and changing it as you change the branch you're working on, either using different configurations on `config/databases.yml`, environment variables or manually changing the database file names.

Comment: it is not in `.gitignore`